# Is there any way to invert every color set within a parent div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Is there any way to invert every color set within a parent div or will I just need to build a new style sheet for it?

Thanks!

Comment: Some more detail would be helpful. When you say "invert" do you actually mean to completely invert the colors? Do you want to do this on the fly using JavaScript, or in your stylesheet?

Comment: question is not clear . please give more details

Comment: you will have to set the values your self, you just need to know the inverted value

Comment: Terribly worded and very vague question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By "`every color set within a parent div`", I assume that child nodes are wanted too.  Also that both foreground and background colors are to be switched (with border colors an easy mod).

[**See the live demo at jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/yQe9t/1/)

Invert all colors like:

```
var Container   = $("#Container");
invertElementColors (Container);

//--- Now invert all children.
Container.find ('*'). each (function () {
    invertElementColors ( $(this) );
} );
```

Given:

```
function invertElementColors (jNode) {
    jNode.css ( {
        'color' :               function (J, oldColor) {
            return invertRGB_ColorStr (oldColor);
        },
        'background-color' :    function (J, oldColor) {
            return invertRGB_ColorStr (oldColor);
        }
        //--- Add other color properties, like border, as desired.
    } );
}

function invertRGB_ColorStr (oldColorStr) {
    //--- Special case
    if (oldColorStr == 'transparent')   oldColorStr = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)';

    //--- Color is text in RGB format.  EG: rgb(1, 22, 255)
    var colorArray  = oldColorStr.match (/\((\d+),\s?(\d+),\s?(\d+)\)/);

    var newColorStr = $.map (colorArray, function (byte, J) {
                            if (!J) return null;

                            //--- Invert a decimal byte.
                            return Math.abs (255 - parseInt (byte) );
                        }
                    ).join (',');

    return 'rgb(' + newColorStr + ')';
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Work on it at http://jsfiddle.net/cZNRZ/ .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - jsFiddle demo</title>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.js'></script>  
  <style type='text/css'>
    span {color:blue;}
    #hello {color:red;}
  </style>

  <script type='text/javascript'>
  //<![CDATA[ 
function invertColor (rgbString) {
    var parts = rgbString.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
    parts.splice(0, 1);
    parts = $.map(parts,
        function (item) {
           return (255-parseInt(item, 10));
        }
    );
    return 'rgb(' + parts.join(',') + ')';
}
function invertme () {
    $('#hello').parent().find('*').each(function () {
        var color = $(this).css('color');
        $(this).css('color', invertColor(color));
    });
}
$(function () {
  $('#button').click(invertme);
});
  //]]> 
  </script>

</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <span id="hello">Hello</span>
    <span>World</span>
</div>
<input type="button" value="invert" id="button"/>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

A bit late but better late then never:

```
function invert(rgb) {
  rgb = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).join(",").match(/(-?[0-9\.]+)/g);
  for (var i = 0; i < rgb.length; i++) {
    rgb[i] = (i === 3 ? 1 : 255) - rgb[i];
  }

  return rgb.join(", ");
}

console.log(
  invert("rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3)"), // 0, 255, 255, 0.7
  invert("rgb(255, 0, 0)"), // 0, 255, 255
  invert("255, 0, 0"), // 0, 255, 255
  invert(255, 0, 0) // 0, 255, 255
);
```